# Certbot Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY

Tags: ssl-certificate

I try to create my first ssl certificate and i use the follow comand:

`certbot certonly --manual -d *.flexis.cyou --agree-tos --manual-public-ip-logging-ok --preferred-challenges dns-01 --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory --register-unsafely-without-email --rsa-key-size 4096`

The certificate was successful create but everytime i try to access to my domain i receive the message "***Hostname DOES NOT VERIFY***" or get this message too:
[printscreen with warning message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8a0Dh.png) 
What i'm doing wrong ? What i can do to fix it ?
Regards in advance

Comment: `flexis.cyou` is not covered by `*.flexis.cyou`. You need a cert with both on it - i.e. `-d flexis.cyou -d *.flexis.cyou`.

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

A wildcard certificate like `*.flexis.cyou` covers subdomains like `foo.flexis.cyou` and `bar.flexis.cyou`, but it does *not* cover `flexis.cyou`.

<sup>(It also won't cover things like `foo.bar.flexis.cyou` - it's single-level only.)</sup>

A multi-domain certificate must be provisioned by passing both to certbot:

```
-d flexis.cyou -d *.flexis.cyou
```